# python selenium nested looping for two dropdowns where their combination gives a web table as output need to scrap all the data of every combination

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, nested, screen-scraping

python selenium nested looping for two dropdowns where their combination gives a web table as output need to scrap all the data of each of combination using nested loop in python selenium. So once the user selects in the website, a (CITY)  dropdown, and its SUBERB dropdown combination and clicks the output button, he gets a WEBTABLE consisting of five to six columns with 50 -100 records for each combination.
need to scrap data for each combination and store it in CSV and JSON.
tried for a set of combinations but was unable to scrap for all the combinations of dropdowns using nesting in Selenium python

Comment: This question needs more information before community can help, as there is not enough to make it reproducible. Follow this guide: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example